# How to get consistent results for numeric sort?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, sorting, firefox

The numeric sorting gives me different values in different browsers:

```
function compareNumbers(a, b) {
    return a - b;
}

['B', 'C', 'A'].sort(compareNumbers);
```

Chrome and Safari don't change the order but in Firefox I get

```
['A', 'C', 'B']
```

How can I get a consistent ordering across browsers?

What I am actually trying to achieve is to sort an array both numerically and lexicographically. In Chrome and Safari, for example,

```
[5, 11, 'B', 'C', 8, 'A'].sort().sort(compareNumbers);
```

seems to achieve the task, i.e.

```
[5, 8, 11, 'A', 'B', 'C']
```

while in Firefox I have to do

```
[5, 11, 'B', 'C', 8, 'A'].sort().reverse().sort(compareNumbers);
```

to get the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change the comapreFuncion like this:

```js
const arr = [5, 11, 'B', 'C', 8, 'A']
arr.sort((a, b) => a - b || a.toString().localeCompare(b.toString()))
console.log(arr)
```

If both of the items being compared are numbers, subtraction will decide the order. If one of them is an alphabet, `a-b` will return `NaN` which is a [`falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value. Then, the second condition in `||` will be checked and they will be alphabetically sorted using [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

Comment: Seems to work well. Any idea whether the diverging results from the question between Safari/Chrome and Firefox are a bug on some side?

Comment: Working fine on `chrome`, `fireFox`, `safari`

Comment: @Daniel browsers have [different implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description) to handle compareFunction. `a-b` returns `NaN` for most of the scenario and each browser handle it differently.